# Jumping to end of python output buffer in emacs

Tags: python, emacs

When using python-mode, py-execute-buffer puts the output in a *Python Output* buffer. I'm nearly always interested in seeing the end of that output, not the beginning. How can I configure emacs so that it automatically jumps to the bottom of the buffer, instead of starting at the top, when it first appears?

Comment: I don't know of any way to configure this to happen automatically, but are you aware of `M->`? This will send you to the bottom of whatever buffer you're in. Also, to hop between outputs `M-}` and `M-{` work well.

Comment: @Wilduck: If you know the key-binding (e.g. `M->`), you can get the function name using `C-h k` followed by `M->` (or whatever). Once you have the function name, calling it automatically is usually easy.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis Sure, but only if you have a hook for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any hooks for that, but it can be done with some advising. This code attaches and idle timer with 0 timeout to `py-postprocess-output-buffer`, so that is executed after output postprocessing is done and control is given back to the user:

```
(defadvice py-postprocess-output-buffer (after my-py-postprocess-output-buffer activate)
  (run-with-idle-timer 0 nil (lambda ()
                               (let ((output-win (get-buffer-window py-output-buffer))
                                     (orig-win (selected-window)))
                                 (when output-win
                                   (select-window output-win)
                                   (end-of-buffer)
                                   (select-window orig-win))))))
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom -- that totally does it.